Setting up i18n in Angular 17 for Multi-Language Support
I'm currently working on an Angular 17 application and I'm looking to implement internationalization (i18n) to support multiple languages. Specifically, I need to set up a dropdown in my application that allows users to select their preferred language, and upon selection, the entire application should be translated accordingly.
I've been searching for resources or tutorials on how to achieve this in Angular 17, but most of the information I've found seems to be for older versions of Angular or doesn't cover the specifics I need.
Can someone provide guidance or point me in the right direction on how to set up i18n in Angular 17 for multi-language support? Any recommendations for libraries, tutorials, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.
Github repo link for how I want to use localisation -https://github.com/nidhi-rathee/i18n-angular17

Questions seeking recommendations for tutorials or libraries are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Did you check the official Angular i18n guide?

Yes, I did. First of all the documentation is very confusing. I was able to generate locale files like en.json, fr.json but afterwords there was no detail to handle the localisation dynamically on the application like changing the current locale based on user options.
Angular doc is more relying on deploying multiple locale application.

Yeah this is how it works. But you can fulfill the requirements with this approach. On selection in the dropdown, you can redirect the browser to a different URL. If you want to have translation on runtime, you cannot use Angular i18n.

You can also check this blog post I wrote. I have tried to show a clear guide on how to implement it. https://lejdiprifti.com/2024/05/20/configure-i18n-in-angular-17/

Super useful @LejdiPrifti, thanks!
